# How to get rid of input/output error for a file created using with statement in python?

Tags: python, input, output, valueerror

process1.py

```
import sys
with open("Main.txt", "w+") as sys.stdout:
    eval(c)
```

In this code value of c was already defined and text file was also created but it raised this error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` when I tried to print the text file `Main.txt` using this code

```
import process1
f = open("Main.txt", "r")
for x in f:
  print(x)
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
with open("Main.txt", "w+") as file:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
       ...
```

The code you wrote literally assigns the newly opened file to the variable `sys.stdout`, executes the wrapped code, and then calls `close(sys.stdout)`.  But `sys.stdout`'s value is still the closed file.